# How can downgrades be enabled for an app?

Tags: android

It seems like the default behaviour of android is that downgrades are prohibited based on the version code: "The Android system uses the versionCode value to protect against downgrades by preventing users from installing an APK with a lower versionCode than the version currently installed on their device."

Is it possible to override this behaviour and thus allow such a downgrade?

Comment: Downgrades are just by definition not recommended so there's no other option than uninstalling app completely before installing an older version. You probably have to wipe out all user data as well since it's not possible to downgrade stuff like database schemas etc.

Comment: The only workaround that can allow downgrades is adding an export/import feature into your app so the user could save the app-private data, uninstall the app (removes the user data), install the old version and restore user data from exported backup.